# Matcher.replaceAll - Chokes on $,\ in replacement String

Tags: java, regex

So I just ran into the nice edge case where doing a `replaceAll` on a String will choke if the replacement String has a $ or \ in it.

Why is the replacement String not just a drop in replace for matches with the regular expression I dictate? What am I not understanding about regular expressions here?

Quote from [Oracle Java 7 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> public String replaceAll(String replacement)
>
> Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the
>   pattern with the given replacement string.
>
> This method first resets this matcher. It then scans the input
>   sequence looking for matches of the pattern. Characters that are not
>   part of any match are appended directly to the result string; each
>   match is replaced in the result by the replacement string. The
>   replacement string may contain references to captured subsequences as
>   in the appendReplacement method.
>
> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

Comment: Because `$` and \ are used in regular expressions as special characters, you have to escape them in the replacement string.

Comment: Because the replacement string has the capacity to backreference the matches from the matcher pattern (using `$`), and as a result you also need to treat `\` specially because it is used to escape `$` characters (to make them literals instead of backreferences). You actually quoted the part of the docs that explains this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dollar sign is a special character; you must escape it:

```
"\\$"
```

Note the double backslash - that's how you code a single backslash in java, which means `\$` is passed to the replace method.

A dollar sign indicates a back reference to a captured group:

```
"$1" // replace with group 1
"$2" // replace with group 2
```

And there's a special zeroth group:

```
"$0" // replace with the entire match
```

Comment: You answer also contains the other answer, \ is a special character too that needs to be escaped.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you~

Answer (score 4):

As the question was stated as why:

Referring to a captured group in your input, replacement strings can contain pieces of whatever you were matching:

`replaceAll("some str(ing)", "another str$1");`

will effectively replace "some" with "another". (Silly example, but to give you an idea of what it means.)

Comment: The example was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Only just noticed your name; I approve ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit funny, but your quote contains the answer (they say that a good question has half of the answer in it. Indeed ;).

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

Escape them with an extra slash.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$` can be used to make a backreference to the matched string (or groups of the matched string) and `\` can be used to disable that behaviour.

If you want to replace with a simple, non-regex string, use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String regex = ...;
String input = ...;
String replacement = ...;
input.replaceAll(regex, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```